# How do i disable this on screen keyboard which appears when playing various games with xbox one controller?

Tags: windows-10, game-controller, xbox-one

How do I disable this virtual [keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aa0UM.jpg) which appears when I play multiple games on Windows 10 with xbox one controller. I am not familiar whether it is the controller feature, windows feature, origin or steam or something else entierly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turned out to be a [Steam Overlay Virtual Keyboard](https://www.google.pl/search?q=steam+virtual+keyboard&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-sdu9ts_SAhVjb5oKHaUUB_MQ_AUIBigB&biw=1920&bih=974) and you can either disable Steam or [do it in a bit different way](https://steamcommunity.com/app/353370/discussions/0/358415738183388695/)